# Расчет методов в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Уточните, пожалуйста, как рассчитываются/вызываются методы которые унаследованы от MonoBehaviour. Как вообще программа понимает что этот метод существует.
Допустим OnCollisionEnter или OnTriggerEnter.
Они же по факту находятся вне Update или FixedUpdate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35010750/6808809

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Вообщето они не наследуются от `MonoBehaviour`, нет никакого `override`. Поэтому их и называют "Magic Methods" (Магические методы). Хотя на самом деле никакой магии, просто [рефлексия](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.reflection.typeinfo?view=net-7.0). Использовать её в собственной архитектуре не стоит.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ